# biblatex and empty "In()"

Tags: biblatex

I use a .bib file as such:

```
@article{juniper,
    author = "Checkoway et al",
    title  = "A Systematic Analysis of the Juniper Dual EC Incident",
    year =   "2016",
    url = {http://eprint.iacr.org/2016/376}
}
```

which shows up with an empty `In: ()` if the "year" field is empty. Or a weird `In: (year)` if the year is specified. Any idea on how to avoid that?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `journal` (or `journaltitle`) field is mandatory for `@article` entries. So if a source wasn't published in a journal, it probably doesn't qualify as an `@article`. Depending on what exactly you have there you can go with the generic `@misc` or `@online` or with the more specific `@report`.

For me this looks like a `@report`

```
@report{juniper,
  author   = {Stephen Checkoway and Shaanan Cohney and Christina Garman and Matthew Green and Nadia Heninger and Jacob Maskiewicz and Eric Rescorla and Hovav Shacham and Ralf-Philipp Weinmann},
  title    = {A Systematic Analysis of the {Juniper} Dual {EC} Incident},
  url      = {http://eprint.iacr.org/2016/376},
  date     = {2016-04-14},
  number   = {2016/376},
  type     = {Cryptology ePrint},
}
```

PS: The [cite function](http://eprint.iacr.org/eprint-bin/cite.pl?entry=2016/376) on the eprint archive suggests a `@misc` type.

Comment: awesome! Didn't know they had snippets for latex citing! This is practical. Any idea how I can avoid the url and the full list of author in \fullcite?

Comment: @David天宇Wong Probably `maxcitenames=1` for the options and `\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{url}}`.